# Comparing two data sets for a trend in the data

Tags: mean, skewness, trend

I have two data sets ( have only access to the statistics of data sets like mean, percentile, count etc but not the data it self). I am interested if I could have a metric which can answer below question:

Pick a random point each from the data set(s) and with great confidence I should be able to say whether one point is going to greater than other, if possible o/w say "not possible to comment".

MY IDEA: My plan is to use difference in the means of the two data sets and also some how try to factor in the metric of skewness of the two data sets. But fail to quantify that in terms of any expression.